# Result from Dicom4che call does not show umlaut characters

Tags: java, dcm4che

I am using dcm4che to perform a query to the PACS, to search for patients. German patients are found by the search criteria (That has umlaut characters) but returning names have <?> characters instead of umlaut. How can I fix this?

```
private void setCharacterSet(Attributes attributes) {
        int tag = Tag.SpecificCharacterSet;
        VR vr = ElementDictionary.vrOf(tag, attributes.getPrivateCreator(tag));
        attributes.setString(tag, vr, "ISO_IR 110");
    }
```

I did add this character set but I don't think it's correct

Comment: make sure encoding set properly at server and client side https://www.baeldung.com/java-char-encoding#4-can-we-override-the-default-charset

Comment: @özkanpakdil encoding is set on server by using <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>